# Moving a backup directory with hard links

Tags: rsync

I have a script to create backup that uses **rsync**. Now I'd like to organize the folder moving the older backups to a empty folder above. And I'd like to keep all hard-links and use that as reference to **rsync** news backups. In sumary I'd like to move the complete backup structure that I have to a new folder (same volume), and my doubt what I could use for that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to reinvent `rsnapshot` - have you looked at that to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do...

```
pax -rwl /some/tree /hardlinked/tree
```

I think you should go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answers, I found a simpler solution, since I'm moving to the same disc, **mv** did the work perfectly for me. And the answer is in the wiki page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv

*"Moving files within the same file system is generally implemented differently than copying the file and then removing the original. On platforms that do not support the rename syscall, a new link is added to the new directory and the original one is deleted. **The data of file is not accessed**."*